# I can't draw a semi-circle in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm new to LaTEX and pgfplots and have been trying to draw a semi-circle but keep getting a weird parabola. How can I fix this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = \(x\),
    ylabel = {\(f(x)\)},
]
%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{sqrt{9-x^2} };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Please don't post code fragments. Instead, edit your question to show a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: If you change the braces in `sqrt{9-x^2}` into parentheses like `sqrt(9-x^2)`, then that should solve your problem. (You may also want to pass in the option `axis equal` after `\begin{axis}` to ensure the graph is to scale.)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis equal,
            axis lines = center,
            xlabel = \(x\),
            ylabel = {\(f(x)\)},
            xmin=-3.5,
            xmax=3.5,
            ]
            %Below the red semicircle is defined
            \addplot [line width=2pt,
            domain=-3:3, 
            samples=100, 
            color=red,
            ]
            {sqrt(9-x^2) };     
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: At `article` document class the default font size is `10pt` , but after  code line `\usepackage{pgfplots}`  I would add the line `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`.